# Proper cmd line for ExifTool for pdf meta tagging

Tags: macos, pdf, exiftool

I'm having issues getting exiftools to write custom meta tags for my pdf files.  In MacOS terminal with exiftools installed.  Here's a sample command.

```
exiftool -overwrite_original -config 
new.config -XMP::pdfx:document_id=”7A 2017 091 d” -XMP::pdfx:description=”Booklet on stuff and more stuff” pdf_files/7A_2017_091_d.pdf
```

Here's the config lines:

```
#user-defined pdfs
%Image::ExifTool::UserDefined = (
    'Image::ExifTool::XMP::pdfx' => {
        document_id => { },
        description => { },
    },
);
1;  #end
```

All I get back is:

```
Warning: Tag 'XMP::pdfx:Document_id' is not defined
Warning: Tag 'XMP::pdfx:Description' is not defined
Nothing to do.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that the entirety of your config file?  Are you including the path to the config file after `-config`?

Comment: Sorry, had to push over the four spaces.  The config file is in the same directory

Comment: I don't create new tags that often, so I'm not posting as an answer yet.  I'm pretty sure your tag names on the command line should be `XMP-pdfx:document_id` and `XMP-pdfx:description`.   Also, does your config file end with `1; `.  You may also need to add to the tag definition to write to it e.g. `document_id => {  Writable => 'string', },`  I'm looking at [this post](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,6208.msg30680.html#msg30680) as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the config file that worked for me:

```
#user-defined pdfs
%Image::ExifTool::UserDefined = (
    'Image::ExifTool::XMP::pdfx' => {
        document_id => { Writable => 'string', },
        description => { Writable => 'string',},
    },
);
1;  #end
```

And the command line with results (you don't need the config file to read XMP tags, just write)

`C:\>exiftool -config temp.txt -xmp-pdfx:document_id="test" -xmp-pdfx:description="Description Test" y:/!temp/test.pdf`
`1 image files updated`

`C:\>exiftool -xmp-pdfx:document_id -xmp-pdfx:description y:/!temp/test.pdf`
`Document id                     : test`
`Description                     : Description Test`